# Question About the Proof of Absolute Continuity of the Total Variation Function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying about the proof of the absolute continuity of the total variation function on Royden and Fitzpatrick's real analysis book. He proceeds to prove it by:

> Let $\epsilon >0$. Choose $\delta$ as a response to the $\epsilon /2$ challenge in regarding the criterion for the absolute continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]$. Let $\{(c_k,d_k)\}_{k=1}^n$ be a disjoint collection of open subintervals of $(a,b)$ for which $\sum_{k=1}^n[d_k-c_k]<\delta$. For $1\leq k \leq n$, let $P_k$ be a partition of $[c_k,d_k]$. By the choice of $\delta$ in relation to the absolute continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]$, $$\sum_{k=1}^nV(f_{[c_k,d_k]},P_k)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

I have a hard time verifying this claim because if we let $P_k=\{c_k,x_1,x_2,...,x_{}n-1,d_k\}$ be a partition of $[c_k,d_k]$, then $|f(d_k)-f(c_k)|\leq V(f_{[c_k,d_k]},P_k)$ by triangle inequality, we can't expect to use the transitive property of inequalities and the absolute continuity criterion to show the above inequality. This confuses me, can someone help me verify the expression above?

Edit: We have the hypothesis that $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$; I want then to prove that the total variation function $x \mapsto TV(f_{[a,x]})$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include a statement of what you're trying to prove: If $f$ is absolutely continuous then the total variation function of $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Say the total variation function is $V(x)$ (I don't know what notation the book uses). Note that if $c<d$ then $$|V(d)-V(c)|=V(d)-V(c)=V_{[c,d]}(f).$$
So we need to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ suuch that if $c_k$ and $d_k$ are as in your post then $$\sum V_{[c_k,d_k]}(f)<\epsilon.$$Now since $$V_{[c,d]}(f)=\sup_PV_{[c,d]}(f,P),$$where $P$ runs over all partitions of $[c,d]$, it's enough to get $$\sum V_{[c_k,d_k]}(f,P_k)<\epsilon/2$$for any choice of partitions $P_k$ of $[c_k,d_k]$.And that last inequality is immediate from our choice of $\delta$! Beccause if we consider the collection of all the little intervals in $P_1$ plus all the little intervals in $P_2$, etc, the sum of the lengths of *all* those little intervals is less than $\delta$.

Comment: So, since the sum of all those little intervals, say $(x_{i-1},x_i)$ is less than $\delta$ then the sum of the all the absolute value of the difference $f(x_i)-f(x_i)$ is less than $\epsilon /2$. But that sum is actually, equivalent to $\sum_{k=1}^n V(f_{[c_k,d_k]},P_k)$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: Phew, thanks. This one gave me a headache.

Comment: What doesn't kill you makes you stronger, heh.